# What can negatively affect linear regression predictiion accuracy with cross validation but not regularization models like lasso regression

Tags: regression

I use sklearn by the way, and I deal with this data set
[image]

After adding dummy variables, and doing the train test split, I get really bad linear regression results with cross validation.
[image]

However, with lasso regression, I do not have the same issue
[image]

What could be causing the linear regression to perform so bad with cross val while lasso doing better?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Could you describe this "phenomenon" more specifically?  "Predictive powers," "what," and "absurd values" are too vague to enable a good response to your question.

Comment: How many observations do you have, and how many features do you have? // Which scores do you want to compare? It looks like you have a much higher $R^2$ for the OLS linear model ($\sim0.9$) than for the LASSO model ($0.48$). // How is $R^2$ calculated in the cross-validation function?

Comment: I have (1759) observations and (186) features after converting categorical data to dummy columns. cross- validation supposedly creates train test folds and gives out a result depending on a metric you specify ,"R2" in my case. I guess my issue is basically why cross validation in linear model does so bad?